# python tkinter- more than one windows to show and do different processes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI application. It has more than one windows. Main windows is updating every second with new values. I am using threading and queue here. There is a button in the main window. Pressing it will open a new window. What I want is, when new window is shown, stop the process in the main window (updating the values process) and some new process will be shown in the new window. Closing the new window should revoke the main window again and continue the process. Do i need to use multi threading or multi processing? 
Unfortunately, I am asking this question for the second time. sorry for that.

```
import tkinter
import time
import threading
import random
import queue

class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self, master, queue, endCommand,newWindow):
        self.queue = queue
        self.pause = False
        # Set up the GUI
        console = tkinter.Button(master, text='Done', command=endCommand)
        console.pack()

        console2 = tkinter.Button(master, text='New', command=newWindow)
        console2.pack()

        self.output = tkinter.StringVar()
        #output.set(1)
        output_1_label = tkinter.Label(master, textvariable= self.output, height=2, width=12)
        output_1_label.pack()
        # Add more GUI stuff here
        self.temp_process()

    def temp_process(self):
        if not self.pause:
            print ("handling messages")
        else:
            print ("Not handling messages")
        root.after(1000,self.temp_process)


    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(0)
                print (msg)
                self.output.set(msg)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

class ThreadedClient:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Create the queue
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

        # Set up the GUI part
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue, self.endApplication,self.create_window)

        self.running = 1
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread1)  #this is for sending data to queue.
# what about second window?
        self.thread1.start()
        self.periodicCall()

    def on_quit(self):
        self.gui.pause = False
        self.window.destroy()

    def create_window(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
        self.gui.pause = True
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.on_quit)

    def periodicCall(self):
        self.gui.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
        self.master.after(1000, self.periodicCall)

    def workerThread1(self):
        while self.running:
            time.sleep(rand.random() * 1)
            msg = rand.random()
            self.queue.put(msg)

    def endApplication(self):
        self.running = 0
rand = random.Random()
root = tkinter.Tk()
client = ThreadedClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your function `processIncoming` check for a flag, and pause/resume when required.

```
class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self, master, queue, endCommand,newWindow):
        self.queue = queue
        self.pause = False
        ....

    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize() and not self.pause:
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(0)
                print (msg)
                self.output.set(msg)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually I have some complex process inside thread. I didn't add it to the post to reduce the code size. Let me try your code.

Comment: why did you say thread is not doing anything? `def workerThread1(self):` is generating a random number and sending it to main gui through queue. I will use this in a later case to show it on GUI (using `tkinter.StringVar()`). when i press the new button it should stop in the main window and another process should happen in new window screen (for demonstation, i am just trying to send and show a random number on this new window)

Comment: I ran your code and there is no output, so they are not required in your minimal example. Besides, your problem doesn't really have to do with `threads` - you just want the main process to `pause` and `resume` upon the new window opens and closes, is it not?

Comment: I tried to reduce the code in my post. So i guess i missed some contents. Actually i am using this code to show some live sensor data in GUI screen. In my actual code, as there is a while loop, i should use threading to avoid freezing of GUI.  And to do some test on sensors, i need another window. That's what i am trying to create. this new window should pause the working main window

Comment: I posted the complete code. Could you please try it once again. Its been two days i am trying to fix it.!!

Comment: Edited as mentioned.

Comment: wow. this is exactly what i was looking for:)). now if i can show a new process in new window, like one i showed in my main window ( displaying a random number ), i am done.  one more doubt.  do I need another thread to do it?

Comment: I can't exactly tell, but from the looks of your current setup you shouldn't need to.